# C++ pthread blocking queue deadlock (I think)

Tags: c++, pthreads, deadlock, blockingqueue

I am having a problem with pthreads where i think i am getting a deadlock. I have created a blocking queue which I thought was working, but after doing some more testing I have found that if i try and cancel multiple threads that are blocking on the blocking_queue, i seem to get a deadlock.

The blocking queue is very simple and looks like this:

```
template <class T> class Blocking_Queue
{
public:
    Blocking_Queue()
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&_lock, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&_cond, NULL);
    }

    ~Blocking_Queue()
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&_lock);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&_cond);
    }

    void put(T t)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);
        _queue.push(t);
        pthread_cond_signal(&_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);
    }

     T pull()
     {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);
        while(_queue.empty())
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&_cond, &_lock);
        }

        T t = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);

        return t;
     }

priavte:
    std::queue<T> _queue;
    pthread_cond_t _cond;
    pthread_mutex_t _lock;
}
```

For testing, I have created 4 threads that pull on this blocking queue. I added some print statements to the blocking queue and each thread is getting to the pthread_cond_wait() method. However, when i try to call pthread_cancel() and pthread_join() on each thread the program just hangs.

I have also tested this with just one thread and it works perfectly.

According to documentation, pthread_cond_wait() is a cancellation point, so calling cancel on those threads should cause them to stop execution (and this does work with just 1 thread). However pthread_mutex_lock is not a cancelation point. Could something be happening along the lines of when pthread_cancel() is called, the canceled thread aquires the mutex before terminating and doesn't unlock it, and then when the next thread gets canceled it cannot aquire the mutex and deadlocks? Or is there something else that I am doing wrong.

Any advice would be lovely. Thanks :)

Comment: Try using [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#helgrind), it's been useful in the past for me for spotting race conditions and deadlocks.

Comment: Cancellation can be treacherous.  Please show us more of your logic:  what's the cancelability state of your worker threads?  What cleanup handlers?  And exactly how are you sequencing the calls to cancel/join on multiple threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_cancel()` is best avoided.

You can unblock all your threads blocked on Blocking_Queue::pull() by throwing an exception from there.

One weak spot in the queue is that `T t = _queue.front();` invokes the copy constructor of T that may throw an exception, rendering you queue mutex locked forever. Better use C++ scoped locks.

Here is an example of graceful thread termination:

```
$ cat test.cc
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

struct BlockingQueueTerminate
    : std::exception
{};

template<class T>
class BlockingQueue
{
private:
    boost::mutex mtx_;
    boost::condition_variable cnd_;
    std::list<T> q_;
    unsigned blocked_;
    bool stop_;

public:
    BlockingQueue()
        : blocked_()
        , stop_()
    {}

    ~BlockingQueue()
    {
        this->stop(true);
    }

    void stop(bool wait)
    {
        // tell threads blocked on BlockingQueue::pull() to leave
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx_);
        stop_ = true;
        cnd_.notify_all();

        if(wait) // wait till all threads blocked on the queue leave BlockingQueue::pull()
            while(blocked_)
                cnd_.wait(lock);
    }

    void put(T t)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx_);
        q_.push_back(t);
        cnd_.notify_one();
    }

    T pull()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx_);

        ++blocked_;
        while(!stop_ && q_.empty())
            cnd_.wait(lock);
        --blocked_;

        if(stop_) {
            cnd_.notify_all(); // tell stop() this thread has left
            throw BlockingQueueTerminate();
        }

        T front = q_.front();
        q_.pop_front();
        return front;
    }
};

void sleep_ms(unsigned ms)
{
    // i am using old boost
    boost::thread::sleep(boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(ms));
    // with latest one you can do this
    //boost::thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
}

void thread(int n, BlockingQueue<int>* q)
try
{
    for(;;) {
        int m = q->pull();
        printf("thread %u: pulled %d\n", n, m);
        sleep_ms(10);
    }
}
catch(BlockingQueueTerminate&)
{
    printf("thread %u: finished\n", n);
}

int main()
{
    BlockingQueue<int> q;

    // create two threads
    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread(boost::bind(thread, 1, &q));
    tg.create_thread(boost::bind(thread, 2, &q));
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
        q.put(i);
    sleep_ms(100); // let the threads do something
    q.stop(false); // tell the threads to stop
    tg.join_all(); // wait till they stop
}

$ g++ -pthread -Wall -Wextra -o test -lboost_thread-mt test.cc

$ ./test
thread 2: pulled 1
thread 1: pulled 2
thread 1: pulled 3
thread 2: pulled 4
thread 1: pulled 5
thread 2: pulled 6
thread 1: pulled 7
thread 2: pulled 8
thread 1: pulled 9
thread 2: finished
thread 1: finished
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution to my problem, thanks for sharing it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly familiar with pthread_cancel() - I prefer cooperative termination.

Wouldn't a pthread_cancel() leave your mutex locked? I suppose you need to cleanup with a cancellation handler.

Comment: In theory when pthread_cond_wait() is called, the mutex should be released (and it is, because multiple threads make it to the pthread_cond_wait() statement). However when pthread_cancel is being called it is looking like the mutex is being required, at least that is my explanation for it.

Comment: The mutex shalll actually be reacquired (if pthread_cond_wait() is cancelled). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html "A condition wait (whether timed or not) is a cancellation point. 

When the cancelability enable state of a thread is set to PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, a side effect of acting upon a cancellation request while in a condition wait is that the mutex is (in effect) re-acquired before calling the first cancellation cleanup handler."

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar experience with pthread_cond_wait() / pthread_cancel(). I had issues with a lock still being held after the thread returned for some reason, and it was impossible to unlock it, since you have to unlock in the same thread as you locked. I noticed these errors when doing pthread_mutex_destroy() since I had a single producer, single consumer situation so the deadlock didn't occur.

pthread_cond_wait() is supposed to lock the mutex when returning, and this could have happened, but the final unlock didn't go through since we forcefully canceled the thread. For safety I generally try to avoid using pthread_cancel() altogether since some platforms don't even support this. You could use a volatile bool or atomics and check if thread should be shut down. That way, the mutexes will be handled cleanly as well.